# History not visible in VSS, now what?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I've been tasked with "fixing" an old VSS database. At this point in time, we are considering migrating to TFS, but for the time being, if we could get VSS back to a stable condition, it would provide some peace of mind.

We're starting to get worried that VSS is going to die on us, because when we try to view the history of any file, nothing seems to happen -- the dialogue appears to just be dismissed. That said, we don't seem to have any problems doing check outs and check ins from Visual Studio, and comparing a changed file to the latest from VSS seems to work (though I doubt this is a functionality of VSS and more of Visual Studio).

I made a backup of the project folder, and ran the Analyze utility, which said it didn't find any problems. I'm not sure what else to try. Help!

We're running VSS 2005 on Windows 2000.

Comment: what version of VSS is the database? v 5 or 6? What client VSS 6d or 2005?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the issue?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910793/en-us?spid=10433&sid=global

Comment: Indeed it is, and I was just coming back to post that I had found that. :)